# How to fix pip being proken after installing line_profiler?

Tags: python, linux, pip

Using Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS. Tried to install line_profiler with `sudo pip3 install line_profiler`, and now when I run `sudo pip3`, I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    import packaging.requirements
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 59, in <module>
    MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

Get a similar error when I try to run a django application now, so I guess a lot of stuff is messed up.

Anyone have any idea of what could have went wrong or how to fix?

Comment: I'm not sure what would cause this, but one idea would be to delete the locally installed packages from `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages` (or move them out of the way) and try again.

Comment: I typically recommend to NOT install via `sudo pip` or `sudo pip3` on a Linux distro. The advantage of a Linux distro is that the distro package manager (APT for Ubuntu) is managing software and updates for you, and you lose a lot of that if you start `sudo pip` (or `sudo make install`, etc.) yourself. Instead, I suggest sticking with distro-provided Python packages or using virtualenv to install what you need. That way, if a virtualenv gets messed up, it's trivial to deactivate and delete it and start over.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've just encountered the same error on a relatively fresh Ubuntu 14.04 config after installing just a couple packages. I'm guessing buggy code has been pushed to a repository.

Look at the root cause of the exception:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 59, in <module>
    MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

The problem is that the `MARKER_EXPR()` call should have a 'name' argument but it doesn't. My fix was to edit the `requirements.py` file such that it contained `MARKER_EXPR("")`. This solved it for me.

Comment: that fixed it for me as well, just change `MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")` to `MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR(""))("marker")`

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this myself and reported it as a bug in packaging, but a maintainer [explained](https://github.com/pypa/packaging/issues/94) that this is due to an outdated version of pyparsing. Upgrading to pyparsing>=2.0.2 should fix the error.

Comment: Download the [pyparsing sources](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Download+and+Installation), go to the `src` directory and run `python setup.py install`

Comment: DIdn't fix it for me

Answer (score 0):

just do `sudo pip uninstall pyparsing`, afterward `sudo pip install pyparsing`, then every thing will be ok.

Comment: I was getting this error from `update-manager` on Ubuntu Trusty. I was able to `sudo -H pip3 install pyparsing --upgrade` to get a new version which didn't throw a TypeError.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer worked for me. However, as noted in another answer, pyparsing needed updating. After adding the quotes in requirements.py, I was able to upgrade pyparsing. I then removed my edit, and pip continued functioning correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem (line-profiler broke pip), but [different error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42222096/no-module-named-packaging).

Solved (thanks to Josh's comment) by deleting some locally installed packages (falling back to the OS-provided defaults) and then updating:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources
sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Warning: this command will delete files without asking. YMMV so backup those files first.