# No module named packaging

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip

I work on Ubuntu 14. I install python3 and pip3.
When I try to use pip3, I have this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 70, i
n <module>
    import packaging.version
ImportError: No module named 'packaging'
```

Does anyone know what is the issue?

Comment: show code you used to install and to import `packaging`

Comment: I didn't install `packaging`. Do I need to install it?

Comment: Yes. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/packaging. Install using `pip3 install packaging`

Comment: How did you install python3 and pip3 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand well, the issue that causes confusion in other's replies is that you have an error while running pip itself, which prevents self-updates of pip or installation of the missing package.

As requested, please state *exactly* how you installed Python 3 and pip. Ubuntu 14 does not come with Python 3.5.

For diagnosis, please give the output of

```
which python3
```

that is probably `/usr/bin/python3` and refers to the system-wide python3 while your pip is located in `/usr/local/bin/pip3`.

Suggested solution: Uninstall system pip with `apt-get remove python3-pip` and try again with either `pip3` or `python3.5 -m pip`.

Comment: Here is python installation script:

Comment: ```sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.5```

Comment: pip installation ```sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip```

Comment: What does `which python3` and `which pip3` give? The fact that the location `/usr/local/bin/pip3` appears in your error hints at a non-system install. Can you also give `ls /usr/local/bin`?

Comment: It solve my issue. When I use pip3, the program try to use python3.4. By using python3.5 -m pip ... (instead pip3) it works well. Many thanks!

Answer (score 61):

First update your pip version itself. You can take [a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221473/how-do-i-update-pip-itself-from-inside-my-virtual-environment)

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

And then try to install `packaging`, if its not already installed by now.

```
pip3 install packaging
```

Comment: It worked for me. Using pip 21.0.1, python 3.8.5, in a win 10.

Answer (score 13):

I recently had the same error. Unfortunately none of the other answers solved my problem. Finally installing the following package resolved my issue:

```
sudo apt install python3-packaging
```

For older versions of Python you may need to adjust the command:

```
sudo apt install python-packaging
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue and I solved it by getting the path to my python module on my virtualenv

```
python3.7 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
```

Then I cloned [github repository for Packaging](https://github.com/pypa/packaging)

in one of the directory..
That's about it

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the above.

I had to manually add the libraries to the pyinstaller command as data:

```
.\pyinstaller.exe -F --add-data ".\venv\Lib\site-packages\packaging;packaging" --add-data ".\venv\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager;webdriver_manager" --onefile .\departed_shipments.py
```

Answer (score 0):

switching to pip==23.0 solved the issue with packaging not being recognized as a module, initially I was working with pip==23.3.2.