# Error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packaging

Tags: python, pip, codegen

I am trying to run this repository: https://github.com/facebookresearch/CodeGen

I tried running it on both Windows and Ubuntu, but I am facing same error in both when I run this command present in *install_env.sh*.

```
pip install -v --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir --global-option="--cpp_ext" --global-option="--cuda_ext" ./
```

I checked and I already have the packaging library installed, but the command still says no module named 'packaging'. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but I still get the same error.
How can I fix it?

#### Error

```
Using pip 23.1.2 from /home/meghna/miniconda3/envs/codegen_3_10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
DEPRECATION: --build-option and --global-option are deprecated. pip 23.3 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to use --config-settings. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11859
WARNING: Implying --no-binary=:all: due to the presence of --build-option / --global-option.
Processing /home/meghna/CodeGen/apex
  Running command pip subprocess to install build dependencies
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-68.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl
  Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools
  Successfully installed setuptools-68.0.0 wheel-0.40.0
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Running command Getting requirements to build wheel
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/meghna/miniconda3/envs/codegen_3_10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "/home/meghna/miniconda3/envs/codegen_3_10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/home/meghna/miniconda3/envs/codegen_3_10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-tznejqwh/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-tznejqwh/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-tznejqwh/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packaging'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  full command: /home/meghna/miniconda3/envs/codegen_3_10/bin/python /home/meghna/miniconda3/envs/codegen_3_10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpnoh7u27d
  cwd: /home/meghna/CodeGen/apex
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No module named packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42222096/no-module-named-packaging)

Comment: No, I already have it installed but it's still saying no module named packaging. I have mentioned it above.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:**

```
vim /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py

sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages')
```

**Option 2:**

```
vim pyproject.toml

[build-system]
requires = ["packaging"]
```

Comment: Why does option 1 work?

Answer (score 0):

```
python path 1:/home/meghna/miniconda3/envs/codegen_3_10
python path 2:/tmp/pip-build-env-tznejqwh/overlay/lib/python3.10
```

Comment: use ` pip install -v --no-build-isolation -- no-cache-dir --global-option="--cpp_ext" --global-option="--cuda_ext"`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!

Comment: pip install -v --no-build-isolation --no-cache-dir --global-option="--cpp_ext" --global-option="--cuda_ext" .