# No module named 'packaging'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, tkinter, customtkinter

I am on windows 10 and everytime i try to run my code with `customtkinter` in `vscode` I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packaging'
```

I tried reinstalling Python, I watched some tutorials, but it still doesn't work.

My code:

```
import tkinter
import customtkinter
from pytube import YouTube

# System Settings
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")


app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.geometry("720x480")
app.title("YouTube Downloader")



# Run app
app.mainloop()
```

```
PS C:\Users\dbrav\Desktop\python>  & 'C:\Users\dbrav\pyver\py3121\python.exe' 'c:\Users\dbrav\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '51762' '--' 'C:\Users\dbrav\Desktop\python\main.py' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dbrav\pyver\py3121\Lib\runpy.py", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dbrav\pyver\py3121\Lib\runpy.py", line 88, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\dbrav\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\dbrav\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\dbrav\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "c:\Users\dbrav\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\dbrav\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "c:\Users\dbrav\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.22.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\dbrav\Desktop\python\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import customtkinter
  File "C:\Users\dbrav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\customtkinter\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .windows.widgets.appearance_mode import AppearanceModeTracker
  File "C:\Users\dbrav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .ctk_tk import CTk
  File "C:\Users\dbrav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\ctk_tk.py", line 7, in <module>
    from packaging import version
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packaging'
```

Comment: This code does not import `packaging`.  Where, exactly, does the error happen?  Please show us the full error traceback message.

Comment: message edited, it doesnt work even when i add import packaging

Comment: It looks like `customtkinter` requires `packaging` be installed according to its requirements.txt https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/blob/master/requirements.txt
Maybe you missed something in the installation process of this package?

Comment: i just installed it using pip install, even installed packaging using pip

Comment: *"i try to run my code with customtkinter in vscode"* : What happens if you run the code outside VS Code? For example from PowerShell command prompt?

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's installed? What happens when you run `'C:\Users\dbrav\pyver\py3121\python.exe' -m pip list` in your shell? Does `packaging` appear in the list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No module named packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42222096/no-module-named-packaging)

Answer (score 0):

This was usually caused by the incorrect Python intrepreter.

Ensure that you've chosen the correct python interpreter.

You can use shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type **Python: Select Interpreter**  to choose the python interpreter which you installed the package in.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by running the following code in the terminal

pip install packaging

BINGO.  works perfect